# Mulesoft + Connect with different database servers dynamically using single connector configuration

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule-esb, mulesoft

Connect with different database server dynamically based upon flag or without flag and don't want to use choice connector to connect with other database server because we are using same database configuration more than 1000 times in our project using multiple database connectors. if we use choice connector, we need to apply everywhere in our project. e.g.

Flag True Connect with Oracle database server and Flag False Connect with SQL database server

Answer (score 2):

I assume Mule4.  If you want this for Mule3 should be similar but instead of DataWeave expressions you will need to write MEL.

I was just able to hook to two different DBs, a MySQL and a Derby, using the following `Database Config` global element:

```
<db:config name="Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="af508698-f0a0-44fa-89ee-d67e5d0a5ee8" >
    <db:generic-connection url='#[if (false) "jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/training?user=name&amp;password=pass" else "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/memory:training"]' driverClassName='#[if (false) "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" else "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"]' />
</db:config>
```

You have to ensure I have both JDBC drivers in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: In mule 3 we are unable to write driver class name dynamically see this syntax #[dw('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver when (true ==  true) otherwise com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')]

Comment: or this way #[\"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" when (true ==  true) otherwise "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"]

Comment: Did you try creating two global elements and writing the MEL conditional on the global element instead?

Comment: Yes i tried, can you please suggest the way to update the global property during application execution? I  have to update the values using inbound properties.

Comment: I did try too but I can't get it to work in mule3. I did try to create a bean and pass the `url` and the `driverName` properties to the StandardDataSource class no avail.  Always the class name fails--I do not believe it can be parametrized TBH, after running these test on my end.

Comment: I have same thoughts :)